# OpenID error when running rails server

Tags: openid, omniauth

I finished the tutorial at http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16 and tried to launch the rails server. A few seconds after running rails server, I get an error and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why. Here's a snippet from the error message:

```
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
 `require': no such file to load --
 openid/store/fetchers (LoadError)
         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
 `require'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
 `load_dependency'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in
 `new_constants_in'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
 `load_dependency'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
 `require'
         from /etc/rails_projects/GooFace/config/environments/development.rb:31
```

What is `openid/store/fetchers`? I've seen several other tutorials mention that "require", so why would it cause this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I think it has to do with your omniauth version.  Specify the version of omniauth explicitly in your gem file otherwise you might end up with version 0.0.1 or something weird.  Refer to https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/193.